# Prove that equation has atleast one solution on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

### $$2(\frac{2+|x|}{1+|x|})^{1+|x|} = 5$$

Now I have used wolframalpha to confirm that there are two solutions for this ($\pm$), but I am unsure how to solve it without computation.

I believe this might be an epsilon - delta problem, but I am unsure of how I should go about attacking it.

Any tips or ideas? Thank you for your time.

Note: This is in the reals.

Comment: Call the left hand side $f(x)$. Is $f$ continuous? What is $f(0)$? What is $f(6)$? (Alternatively, write $f(x)=2\bigl(1+1/(1+|x|)\bigr)^{1+|x|}$ and take the limit as $x\rightarrow\infty$ to see $f$ takes values greater than $5$).

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to use the intermediate function theorem. So you have to prove that e.g. the left-hand side is a continuous function of $x$, and then find two values $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that the left-hand side is smaller/larger than 5 at these values. Now use the theorem.

Comment: Yes, this will work well, I am surprised I didn't think of this, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem#Theorem).

If $\mathrm{f}$ is continuous and there is a $u$ for which $\mathrm{f}(u) < 5$ and a $w$ for which $\mathrm{f}(w)>5$ then there must exists a $v$, with $u < v < w$ for which $\mathrm{f}(v)=5$.

Notice that for $x>1$, your function is continuous. In fact it is differentiable. We need to pick values for $u$ and $w$. Well, how about $u=2$ and $w=6$? Can you evaluate $\mathrm{f}(2)$ and $\mathrm{f}(6)$?